# Save the time of font selection with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, performance

I'm using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, with `fontspec` to select text font and `unicode-math` to select math font. On my PC, each time I compile a document, it would cost about 4~5 seconds loading the fonts (not just the first time, but every time I press ctrl+S to save the file). The time used is not very long, but is annoying since I have to wait extra 4s to see the result every time I make a change to the document.

Considered that the font configuration is a static part in the `.cls` file, I wonder if there's any way to save these 4 seconds? (e.g., is it possible to pre-load those fonts, or pre-compile the preamble part?)

I've tried to copy font files to the working folder and use filename of the fonts. However, this doesn't save much time.

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Take about 1s each time
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

% Take about 3s each time
\RequirePackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
    [range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
            "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
            "00D7,"00F7,
            "0131,
            "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
            "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
            "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
            "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
            "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
            "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
            "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
            "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
            "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
            "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
            "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
            "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
            "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
            "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
            "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
            "23DC-"23DF,
            "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
            "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
            "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
            "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
            "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
            "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
        }]

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\[\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\log t}\,dt\]
\end{document}
```